# Google VM RAM for Minecraft Server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, minecraft, ram, minecraft-forge

I've been tasking with creating a Minecraft server for about 500 players. I've never create a Minecraft server this large before and I think the best way to go about it is (how I've done all my other servers) with Google Cloud. Google Cloud has the following VM options:
[image]

I'm thinking about ~100MB per player to be on the safe side, so that's about 50 GB, so I'd say the n2-highmem-8 is probably a good VM to use. Is this overkill? Underkill?

Also, I know that a MC server can't use Multiple CPUs at the same time, so is it a waste paying for 8 Virtual CPUs?

Thanks!

Comment: This [guideline](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/minecraft-server#costs) can be helpful to setting up a Minecraft server. But without doing reproduction and getting the exact workload of each player, it will be hard to determine the overkill and underkill status of your setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 500 players, I would recommend a minimum of 6 vCore and 32 GB or more.

You're right with Minecraft mainly using only one thread, so a high CPU Clock speed is most valuable. Also, I would recommend using [PaperMC](https://papermc.io/), it's a custom-made better performing Minecraft Server software. [Here](https://yivesmirror.com/downloads/paper) could you get different server versions if you do not want to use 1.15.2 Minecraft.

Maybe you should look around for different Servers, near your location. I bet you can find something less expensive and with higher Core clocks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response - ended up not going with google cloud because, as you said, it's super expensive - ended up getting a dedicated server with an AMD Ryzen 9 3900X CPU which should get the job done + I'm using Bungee.

Answer (score -2):

Minecraft has  **FREE** servers in the launcher
[Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncyQt.png)
[Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bGRd.png)